# Can not open vscode in terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Environment information: VMware 16.2.3, Ubuntu22, VScode -1.78.2

I could use `code .` open vscode in the morning, but I can't do this at now, I wonder why.

thanks for answering.

1. change  permermission of the directory.

```
yindec@yindec-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/eosworks/orchestrator/modules/alioth$ sudo chown -R yindec .
[sudo] password for yindec: 
yindec@yindec-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/eosworks/orchestrator/modules/alioth$ code .
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
yindec@yindec-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/eosworks/orchestrator/modules/alioth$
```

2. switch user to root.

```
yindec@yindec-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/eosworks/orchestrator/modules/alioth$ su - root
Password: 
root@yindec-virtual-machine:~# cd /home/yindec/Downloads/eosworks/orchestrator/modules/alioth/
root@yindec-virtual-machine:/home/yindec/Downloads/eosworks/orchestrator/modules/alioth# code .
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument `--no-sandbox` and specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument.
```

I saw other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803343/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-as-root), it is not recommended.

3. I google with the erro keyword "mkdir: cannot create directory", amlost search result is about mkdir.
4. I could open vscode by shortcut.

Comment: The empty directory name is the weirdest part. A few things to try and help with debugging: 1/ can you run VS Code from that directory by just using `code`? 2/ What does `which code` result in? If that gives a filename, 3/ can you do `file $(which code)`?

Comment: answer for the comments:  1. yes, I can.  2. I tried add a filename, it doesn't work `yindec@yindec-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/eosworks$ code docs
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory`  .3. I am sorry, I can't  get the point.

Comment: `which` is a program. `which code` is a command that you run in a shell (invoking the program and passing it `code` as a parameter): which  returns  the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as commands in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the arguments.  It does not canonicalize path names. `file` is also a program